# Can I stop calling emoji pallet when I use F1~12 keys?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, big-sur

I set my Mac such that it shows emoji pallet on the global icon. However, when I use F1~F12 keys, such as decreasing volume, it usually calls the emoji pallet as well as executing the function.

I would like to set my Mac such that only when I click only the global key (fn key) does the emoji pallet appear on the screen, whereas clicking the global key with F1~F12 just does the task. Is this possible?

[image]